Create pdf using Questpdf
I am trying to create a PDF using QuestPDF. I need to design the first page with two columns: the first column should appear only on the first page, while the second column should extend to the next page and span the full width. I tried the code below, but I'm not sure how to break the page after filling the first page and then continue with the remaining content on the second page.
Edit 1
The requirement is that the number of articles should be dynamic, as the length of each article may vary—some may take more than four lines, while others may only take one. The content should flow naturally and break at the end of the first page, depending on the length of the articles.
Below is the code I used to generate the PDF.
using QuestPDF.Fluent;
using QuestPDF.Helpers;
using QuestPDF.Previewer;
namespace AcademicPlatform.Web.Services;
public class GeneratePdfQuestPdf
{
    public void CreateAndPreviewer(List<string> articles)
    {

        Document.Create(container =>
        {
            container.Page(page =>
            {
                page.Size(PageSizes.A4);
                page.Content().Row(row =>
                {

                    // Left Column
                    row.ConstantItem(220).ShowOnce().Background("#163853").Padding(20).Column(leftColumn =>
                    {
                        leftColumn.Item().Text("Left Column Content");
                    });
                    // Right Column
                    row.RelativeItem()
                    // .ShowIf(x => x.PageNumber == 1)
                    .Padding(20).Column(rightColumn =>
                    {
                        rightColumn.Item().Column(col =>
                        {
                            int i = 1;
                            foreach (var item in articles)
                            {
                                col.Item().Row(row =>
                                {
                                    row.RelativeItem().ShowEntire().Text($"{i++}- {item}").FontSize(14).Bold();
                                });
                                col.Item().ShowEntire().PaddingVertical(2).LineHorizontal(0.5f).LineColor("#1F3C88");
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                ;
            });
        }).ShowInPreviewer();
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        QuestPDF.Settings.License = LicenseType.Community;
        var articles = Enumerable.Range(1, 40).Select(i => $"Article {i}").ToList();
        GeneratePdfQuestPdf generatePdfQuestPdf = new GeneratePdfQuestPdf();
        generatePdfQuestPdf.CreateAndPreviewer(articles);
    }
}

The generated pdf is show as:



I don't know if that works and I have no way of trying today, but: what I would try is conditionally expand the span of the right column to both columns if page no > 1

dear @Fildor I tried that, but unfortunately, it didn't work.

Thanks for your comment I update the question

Replacing "row.ConstantItem(220)" with "row.AutoItem().Width(220)" solves the problem. The following code works.
Note 1:
Currently, the output file of the code below is a multi-page PDF file.
"QuestPDF" has an automatic pagination function, but if an additional page break is needed, it can be done with "col.Item().PageBreak()" command.
Note 2:
To see more details, a PDF file "C:\[Temp]\Test.pdf" will also be created after running the code, which can be opened by other tools such as "Acrobat Reader" or "Google Chrome".
PDF file can be created by calling "GeneratePdfQuestPdf.CreatePDF()" method in following code:
GeneratePdfQuestPdf.cs:
public class GeneratePdfQuestPdf
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_ARTICLES = 90;
    const string PATH_OF_PDF_FILE_TO_BE_CREATED = @"C:\[Temp]\Test.pdf";

    public static void CreatePDF()
    {
        QuestPDF.Settings.License = LicenseType.Community;
        var articles = Enumerable.Range(1, NUMBER_OF_ARTICLES).Select(i => $"Article {i}" + GetDummyContentForArticle(i)).ToList();
        var doc = GetPDFDocument(articles);
        doc.GeneratePdf(PATH_OF_PDF_FILE_TO_BE_CREATED);
        doc.ShowInPreviewer();
    }
    private static Document GetPDFDocument(List<string> Articles)
    {
        var doc = Document.Create(container =>
        {
            container.Page(page =>
            {
                page.Size(PageSizes.A4);

                page.Content().Row(row =>
                {
                    // Left Column

                    row.AutoItem().Width(220).ShowOnce().Background("#163853").Padding(20).Column(leftColumn =>
                    {
                       leftColumn.Item().Text("Left Column Content");
                    });

                    // Right Column

                    row.RelativeItem().Padding(20).Column(rightColumn =>
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (var item in Articles)
                        {
                            rightColumn.Item().Row(row =>
                            {
                                row.RelativeItem().ShowEntire().Text($"{i++}- {item}").FontSize(14).Bold();
                            });
                            rightColumn.Item().ShowEntire().PaddingVertical(2).LineHorizontal(0.5f).LineColor("#1F3C88");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
        return doc;
    }
    private static string GetDummyContentForArticle(int ArticleNo)
    {
        int NumberOfLines = ArticleNo % 4;
        string DummyContent = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfLines; i++)
            DummyContent += ((DummyContent != "") ? "\r\n" : "") + "It is a dummy line!";
        return ((DummyContent != "") ? "\r\n" : "") + DummyContent;
    }

}

The output is as follows:


Thank @babak-m for your effort. However, the requirement is that the number of articles should be dynamic, as the length of each article may vary—some may take more than four lines, while others may only take one. The content should flow naturally and break at the end of the first page, depending on the length of the articles.

Ok, thanks @Abdul Hadi for checking my answer. With this criterion that you have given, if another way comes to my mind, I will edit my answer.

@Abdul Hadi, I changed my solution. Regarding the point you said about the variable number of article lines, this code works. As a test, I put a method in the code to create articles with a variable number of lines between 1 and 4 and I tested it.

Hello @BabakM. , Can you send me a link to how to create this project with Visual Studio? I have some problems with .net framework not creating successfully even after removing and recreating.

Hello @Tran Quoc Bao, of course, maybe if the question owner was asked, the answer would be more accurate, but if I want to say, for this:
1- Create a new  .NET Core 6 or higher project in Visual Studio 2022 (WinForms is better)
2- According to your intended use, if you are allowed to use this tool, install the "QuestPDF"  NuGet package in the project ("QuestPDF" is not free for every application) 3- Add the written class.
4- Call the "CreatePDF" method from the class that was written.
5- If the preview of "QuestPDF" does not work properly, open the created PDF file in "Google Chrome".

@Tran Quoc Bao, I usually work with some other PDF creating tools (such as report creating tools and use "Export to PDF"). For more detailed information about "QuestPDF", please ask the questioner and leave a comment under the question.

Thank @BabakM. , i created successfully

Thank you, @BabakM, for the solution! I sincerely appreciate your answer and apologize for not accepting it earlier. I encountered some challenges and unfortunately forgot about the question. My apologies once again, and thank you so much!

@Abdul Hadi, No problem, I'm glad I could help you. Thank you. Since when I answer a question, it's important for me to know if it was useful to others, fortunately the positive feedback of "Tran Quoc Bao" and especially you as the question owner and also choosing my post as the answer to the question was helpful and assured that the answer is usable.

So in QuestPDF, there is a method called "PageBreak" which will send the remaining content after the method is called to a new page. I belive this works with columns.
The following link leads you to the appropriate website that shows it.
https://www.questpdf.com/api-reference/page-break.html
